# Upgrading spring to 5.0.9

Tags: spring, maven

I am trying to bump up Spring from version 4.3.14 to 5.0.9. Here's what my beans specification looks like:

```
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:jaxrs="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
      http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxrs.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.3.xsd">
```

I do not see a XML schema definition file for Spring 5 such as 'spring-context-5.0.xsd' at http://www.springframework.org/schema/context. Is version-less schema the only way to go for Spring 5? Or can I continue using the 4.3 version of xsd's?

Comment: I'd stop using XML. If really that's not possible, I would do what the documentation does: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.9.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/core.html#spring-core

Answer (score 0):

You can use schema without version numbers. 
[https://www.springframework.org/beans/spring-beans.xsd] Currently, it refers to 4.3, but there another link from suggests that with the 'versionless' schema, it would be updated to latest version.

Refer to these for more details:
https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-13499